# Lollipop switch with text does not look good

Tags: android, switchcompat

I am trying to have a yes/no switch in Lollipop. The [Holo Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmK9m.png) actually does this nice. But this is what it looks like on my device:

[image]

How can I make the button background scale with it?
I tried settings a different background (thumb), but that one got cut off. Added padding somewhat fixed it, but hey, this should not be something I need to fiddle around with to get to work..doing that is my backup plan if no-one has an answer here ;)

Someone any ideas?

Comment: Why not putting `text` next to `switch`? To ahieve what you want you can use your own image with `9patch` maybe. Switches on lolipop dont include text and it is suggested to stick to that rule for a better `UX`

Comment: Yeah, probably a better way to go. But as the switch supports it, I expect it to show up correctly. Customer wanted this, so...maybe I should try to get the holo switch in 5.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came to a similar conclusion. Based on my readings around how the new `Switch` / `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` widgets should be used it appears that the right thing to do here is to adjust design to fit with Lollipop or move widget type to radio buttons if appropriate.